# Rails - Show data from Client model on Project model's index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, view

I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but just can't seem to figure it out. So I have a Rails app with a `project` model and a `client` model. A client `has_many` projects and a project `belongs_to` a client. I created a migration to join the two tables that looks like this:

```
class AddClientsProjectsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :clients_projects do |t|
        t.integer :client_id
        t.integer :project_id
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :clients_projects
  end
end
```

All I'm trying to do is show which client a project belongs to on the project INDEX view, inside the project loop. I can do this easily on a project's SHOW page by `<% @project.clients.each do |client|%><%= client.name %><% end%>` with `@project = Project.find(params[:id])` in the show method of the projects controller.

But adding an instance variable like that to the index method and then trying to call it within the `<% @projects.each do |project| %>` loop just does not work!

I at least know the data is being saved correctly since I can display a project's client name on the show page, but I just can't get it to display on the index view.

If it helps, this is how I'm assigning a project to a client (done via the project index page):

```
<%= form_for @project, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
   <% for client in Client.find(:all) %>
   <%= check_box_tag "project[client_ids][]", client.id, @project.clients.include?(client) %>
      <label><%= client.name %></label>
   <% end %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Lastly, this is the code I've been playing around with on the projects index page inside the loop to show which client each project is assigned to:

`<% Client.all do |client| %><%= client.name %><% end %>`

It doesn't work!

Comment: Can you post your models??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong this is what you desire to achieve ???

```
@projects = Project.all

@projects.each do |project|   #looping on all projects
     project.clients.each do |client|  #looping on clients for a project
          client.name 
     end
end
```

Comment: @TrevanHetzel always pleasure to help others if I can :)

Answer (score 0):

I a project belongs_to a client, you just need to add `client_id` on the projects table.  no need for a join table :)  you can access a list of projects for a client by client.projects without doing anything fancy.  on the other hand, if a project can be shared by different clients, you have the right table structure but you need to change your associations.